# jQuery - Reset radio buttons on click

Tags: jquery, click, radio-button, checked, prop

**jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/cCBUh/2/

**Information**

- I have 3 choices. Only click on the labels, not on the radio buttons.
- When clicking on the different labels, different radio buttons are checked.
- In the console it says "clicked" when ever a label is clicked just to make sure that happens.
- When clicking on the same label twice, the console says "checked", telling us it's
  already checked.
- If the label is already checked it should remove the checked from all the radio buttons, resetting it, like it's from the start.

**Problem**

When clicking on the radio button the second time the click don't remove the checked from all the radio buttons. Why is that? Solution?

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel">
    <label for="radio-1">Radio 1</label>
    <label for="radio-2">Radio 2</label>
    <label for="radio-3">Radio 3</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="group-1">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="group-1">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="group-1">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.panel label').on( "click", function(e) {
        console.log('clicked');
        var my_id = $(this).attr('for');
        if( $('.panel #' + my_id).is(':checked') ) {
            console.log('checked');
            $('.panel input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is, that the default click-behaviour on a label with an id-attribute forces this. I changed your javascript to do what you want and added a bit more debug:

http://jsfiddle.net/cCBUh/15/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.panel label').on( "click", function(e) {
        // prevent the html to automatically check the corresponding checkbox
        e.preventDefault();
        var my_id = $(this).attr('for');
        console.log('clicked: ' + my_id);
        if( $('#' + my_id).is(':checked') ) {
            console.log('checked: ' + my_id);
            $('#' + my_id).prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            console.log('check now: ' + my_id);
            $('#' + my_id).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

But you might also want to apply that behaviour to onClick on the radio buttons itself?